# Implementing nested sets in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement the nested set pattern in Haskell. I have a set of users arranged in a tree. They are defined as follows:

```
data User = User {u_id :: Int, parent :: Int, lft :: Int, rgt :: Int} deriving (Show)
data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a [Tree a] deriving (Show, Eq)
```

The data for the u_id and parent comes from a database and I will then have to calculate the lft and rgt values from it. This is the incomplete function I have so far:

```
calcNestedSet :: Tree User -> Tree User
calcNestedSet EmptyTree = EmptyTree
calcNestedSet tree = calcNestedSet' 1 $ resetTree tree
    where
        setLftandRgt u l r = User (u_id u) (parent u) l r
        setLft u l = setLftandRgt u l (rgt u)
        setRgt u r = setLftandRgt u (lft u) r
        resetTree (Node a children) = Node (setLftandRgt a 0 0) $ map resetTree children
        -- If at a leaf, set both the left and the right and return the node
        calcNestedSet' counter (Node a []) = Node (setLftandRgt a counter (counter+1)) []
        -- If at a branch, set the left value and traverse to the next eligible child
        calcNestedSet' counter (Node a children) = Node (setLft a counter) $ map (calcNestedSet' (counter+1)) children
```

However, I can't get my head around solving this functionally without having the ability to look 'back up' the tree to see the parent lft and rgt values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using the left value and the result of applying `nestedSet` to the children of a given element in order to derive the right value.

Consider the following solution

```
data User a = User {u_id :: a, parent :: a, lft :: Int, rgt :: Int} deriving (Show)
data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a [Tree a] deriving (Show, Eq)

nestedSet :: Tree (User a) -> Tree (User a)
nestedSet = snd . nestedSetHelper 1
  where
    nestedSetHelper:: Int -> Tree (User a) -> (Int, Tree (User a))
    nestedSetHelper l EmptyTree = (l, EmptyTree)
    nestedSetHelper l (Node (User {u_id=uid, parent=par}) children) = 
      ((r+1), Node (User uid par l r) new_trees)
      where
        r :: Int
        (r, new_trees) = calcNestedSet (l+1) children
        calcNestedSet :: Int ->
                         [Tree (User a)] ->
                         (Int, [Tree (User a)])
        calcNestedSet leftValue trees =
          foldr func (leftValue, []) trees
          where
            func :: Tree (User a) ->
                    (Int, [Tree (User a)]) ->
                    (Int, [Tree (User a)])
            func t (v, ts) = (new_v, new_t:ts)
              where
                (new_v, new_t) = nestedSetHelper v t
```

`nestedSetHelper` uses the given value for `l` and creates a value for `r` based on computing the children.

Note, I changed the type of `User` so I could run a test on this solution using values on the wikipedia page example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model#Example, and more easily read the results.

With that I created this test.

```
test :: Tree (User String)
test = Node (User "Clothing" "" 0 0)
       [Node (User "Men's" "Clothing" 0 0)
        [Node (User "Suits" "Men's" 0 0 )
         [Node (User "Slacks" "Suits" 0 0) []],
         Node (User "Jackets" "Suits" 0 0) []],
        Node (User "Women's" "Clothing" 0 0)
        [Node (User "Dresses" "Women's" 0 0)
         [Node (User "Evening Gowns" "Dresses" 0 0) [],
          Node (User "Sun Dresses" "Dresses" 0 0) []],
         Node (User "Skirts" "Women's" 0 0) [],
         Node (User "Blouses" "Women's" 0 0) []]]
```

The result differs from the example result on wikipedia, but only in the index values due to a different, although valid, traversal of the tree.

Comment: I think I can see how its done now. Time work more on your base to implement some gaps in the counter so that subtree insertions are possible without modifying the whole tree.

Answer (score 3):

Right now you're only ever pushing the counter "down" the tree. You also need to capture it as it comes back "up"

```
-- For simplicity, we don't really need EmptyTree, assuming we 
-- only care about values stored in the tree
data Tree  a = Node  a [Tree a] deriving Show

-- Universal nested set label, don't need to associate it with 
-- the data in the tree
data Label a = Label a Int Int 

nest' :: Tree a           -- undecorated tree
      -> Int              -- state being passed down
      -> ( Tree (Label a) -- decorated tree
         , Int            -- state being passed up
         )

nest' (Node a []) n = (Node (Label a n (n+1)) [], n+2)
```

All of the above should be fairly obvious, if a little weird. The major point is that I'm adjoining a new "return counter" to the result of `nest'` which passes the counter back "up" the tree. We've currently handled the "no children" case and we can extend that to include children by passing through the child list.

```
nest' (Node a cs) dn =
  let (cslabeled, up) = mapNest' cs (dn+1)
  in  (Node (Label a dn up), up+1)

mapNest' []     dn = ([], dn)
mapNest' (c:cs) dn =
  let (c,  mid) = nest' c dn
      (cs, up ) = mapNest' cs mid
  in (c:cs, up)
```

This logic is a little tough to follow, but it's essentially just a matter of passing the node counter around as we bubble down, up, and across the tree. Fortunately, we can make this a little easier by noting that `Int -> (Tree (Label a), Int)` is just `State Int (Tree (Label a))` and so

```
nest' :: Tree a -> State Int (Tree (Label a))
```

The other big improvement is to notice some duplicated functionality in `nest'` because both `nest'` and `mapNest'` handle the empty child list scenario. All together, we can write monadic nest very simply, focusing only on the primary logic

```
nest' (Node a cs) = do
  d <- get
  let (csl, u) = runState (mapM nest cs) (d+1)
  put (u+1)
  return (Node (Label a d u) csl)
```

and then, run the resulting `State` monad in our top-level API

```
nest :: Tree a -> Tree (Label a)
nest t = evalState (nest' t) 0
```

such that

```
>>> x = Node "hi" [Node "bye" [], Node "go" []]
>>> nest x
Node (Label "hi" 0 5) [Node (Label "bye" 1 2) [],Node (Label "go" 3 4) []]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, I think I lost you at when you introduced `State`. Is that something that is not part of the standard library as I could not get it to compile otherwise. Apologies if its a really stupid question as I am still very new to haskell

Comment: `State` is a very well-known Haskell type. It's available in the `transformers` package as well as the `mtl` package. Monads capture a lot of common patterns (such as stateful traversals) so they are often useful in structuring code.

Comment: Thanks for heads up. I still haven't reached the Monad chapters but I am looking forward to the writing code as terse as the ones you have written above!

Comment: If you study the one which doesn't use monads then you'll also get some good intuition for what exactly State is doing!